# Mergers are at it again

Tags: discussion

I have noticed new discussion of old issue in Area 51 - [CMS/BLOG proposals MERGER](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/cms-blog-proposals-merger/)

I think we have [locally established point of view](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=merge) (*hell no*), but I don't feel it is sufficiently represented at Area 51. So if anyone wants to drop by there and participate in constructive discussion...

Because (tongue-in-cheek) from our side it looks like "you must bail Drupal out" and from their "those elitists - whole site! tag in the corner is good enough for them". :)

Answer (score 7):

Well, this site is about to go public/final. It is very unlikely we'd merge a proposal with a public final site.

Comment: Yep. For clarification I am not worried that we do get merged. I just want it to be clear that site about specific CMS is completely viable and (hopefully) can be very successful in the long run. Some people seem to be very convinced that such site won't ever work and global CMS site is the only way. I want WPSE to be success role model for other CMS proposal, not potential meat to boost generic CMS site. :)

Comment: 100% agreed with @Rarst on this.

Comment: @rarst I don't think that has any chance of actually happening